# adding extra custom chars to preg_replace rule

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$despre = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/",'',$despre);
```

I want to add: `-,:` to the rule and i tryed the below one and it's not working.The below one is what i tryed but not working.

```
$despre = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:,- ]/",'',$despre);
```

I would appreciate if you can help me.
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` has to be first or last in a character class, or escaped or else it denotes a range like in `a-z`:

```
$despre = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:, -]/",'',$despre);
```

Comment: thnx, it's working, i'll accept your answer in 8 mins :)